# Приставка, означающая невысокую степень

Tags: морфемика

Посоветуйте приставку, обозначающую невысокую степень. Псевдо- не совсем подходит, так как совсем отрицает предмет или действие. Суб- - это нечто вспомогательное.

Comment: Важна сочетаемость приставки с конкретным словом - приведите его, пожалуйста.. Из ранее не называвшихся приставок заслуживает внимания **полу-** (значение далеко не всегда соответствует "половине").

Answer (score 3):

НЕДОчеловек, МИКРОблог, ПОЛУботинки, СЛАБОумный, МАЛОмощный...

Answer (score 1):

Лучшее, что нашла, - приставку [недо-](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE), вслушайтесь: *недомогание*... невысокая степень немочи, а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Недозвучал его аккорд
>
> И никого не вдохновил...
>
> Собака лаяла, а кот
>
> Мышей ловил...
>
> Смешно! Не правда ли, смешно!
>
> А он шутил - недошутил,
>
> Недораспробовал вино
>
> И даже недопригубил.
>
> <...>
>
> Смешно, не правда ли, смешно?
>
> А он спешил - недоспешил.
>
> Осталось недорешено,
>
> Все то, что он недорешил...

Answer (score 0):

Судя по "псевдо-" и "лже-" не подойдёт? И "около-"? А вот "мало-" — как раз будет.

Comment: Я бы хотел указать на менее сознательную составляющую человека но все же составляющую часть его внимания. Например, обстановка окружающая среда в момент глубокого погружения в себя, все - таки продолжает существовать. Не знаю, существует ли она в малосознательном или околосознательном.

Comment: Ааа, "второ-", второплановость наверное?

Comment: Мне норовит все-таки к слову "сознательный" ее подобрать

Comment: Мне норовит? Норовит подобрать?